# How do I add an image to a line of text without the white space under the image?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to add an image within a line of text but the white space that is automatically added under the image is throwing off the alignment. The other answers to this question only seem to apply to images when they are not part of a line of text, so are not helpful.

The common answers seem to be
`display: block`, which doesn't work for my use because it adds a line break or `vertical-align`, which doesn't work for my use because it pushes down the next line of text.

Screenshots from wordpress:

[image: screenshots from wordpress]

Does anyone know another solution or workaround?

```css
<style>img {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  margin-top: 3px
}

</style>
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam (<img src="http://www.redacted.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/info-gray.png" alt="" />) quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to put a height on your image to prevent it from pushing the text down. also add width: auto to prevent stretching or squishing of your image.

```
<style>
img {
   vertical-align: text-top;
   margin-top: 3px;

   height: <the size of the text here>;
   width: auto;
}
</style>
```